# Retrieve data type of an object

Tags: c++, oop, arduino

Since the `typeid` operator is disabled in the Arduino compiler, I am looking for a way to detect the type of an object.

I found this handy [code](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/how-to-retrieve-the-data-type-of-a-variable). The author states that it would work for custom classes. But how?

My approach is to put the code in the beginning of the class in that I want to use it in:

```
// Generic catch-all implementation.
template <typename T_ty> struct TypeInfo { static const char * name; };
template <typename T_ty> const char * TypeInfo<T_ty>::name = "unknown";

// Handy macro to make querying stuff easier.
#define TYPE_NAME(var) TypeInfo< typeof(var) >::name

// Handy macro to make defining stuff easier.
#define MAKE_TYPE_INFO(type)  template <> const char * TypeInfo<type>::name = #type;

// Type-specific implementations.
MAKE_TYPE_INFO( numfield )

class numfield{public: numfield();};
    numfield::numfield(){
}
class plus{public: plus(const numfield * nf);};
plus::plus( const numfield * nfIN){
    if (TYPE_NAME(nfIN)=="numfield") {
        nf=nfIN;
    } else {
        Serial.print("Warning: object of ");
        Serial.print(TYPE_NAME(nfIN));
        Serial.println(" type is handed to object of type puls");
    }
};
```

The error:

> numfield is not defined in `MAKE_TYPE_INFO( numfield )`

Comment: You should place `MAKE_TYPE_INFO( numfield )` after `class numfield ` has been declared.  That will do the trick.

Comment: You may be fighting the wrong enemy here. Why do you need to know the type of the object? Can you not provide a base class and a virtual function?

Comment: thanks, but there is a new error... `main.cpp: In constructor 'plus::plus(const numfield*)':

main.cpp:6:34: error: 'typeof' was not declared in this scope

 #define TYPE_NAME(var) TypeInfo< typeof(var) >::name`

Comment: @user4581301 in my actual code numfield and plus are along others of the same base class. But plus will do something with numfield (guess what) that it can only do with a numfield and not e.g. a textfield

Comment: @user7408924 but you know `nfIN` points to a `numfield` because you declared it as such.  Unless `textfield` is a subclass of `numfield`?  Even then, the method you have here deals compile-time types, not runtime types.  `TYPE_NAME(*nfIN)` would always be `"numfield"`.

Comment: @MilesBudnek that seems reasonable. So I would have to check the object that I hand over when I create a plus object. Still the code should be working and `TYPE_NAME(nfIN)=="numfield"`should always be true

Comment: @user7408924 Not really.  `typeof` is non-standard (try `decltype` instead), and `nfIN` is a `const numfield*`, which you don't have a `TypeInfo` specialization for.

Comment: @user7408924 Also, you can't compare C-style strings with `==`.  You have to use `strcmp`.

Comment: @MilesBudnek please note that this is about an arduino project. (Thats for example why I can compare strings with ==) But on the other hand I wonder why the author of the link I posted uses typeof even though it is not supported by arduino. If it was I wouldn't need all of the code above...
Changing the type to a pointer makes of course sence but also doesn't solve the problem :/

Comment: @user7408924 the problem you describe is exactly what polymorphism is intended to solve. That said I think you need to stop and rethink. Why is plus a class as opposed to a free function? If it has to be a class, why is it left in an indeterminate state when it fails to construct?

Comment: Hm... You might be right, Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: If `==` works for C strings in this context, it's because the compiler has interned both constants to the same address. I wouldn't count on that being the case 100% of the time.

Comment: What *is* your problem? What are you trying to build? It doesn't look lile your example code is doing anything meaningful.

Comment: @MarkRansom "The operator == and the method equals() perform identically. " [link] (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringComparisonOperators)

Comment: @n.m. I am building a menue on a tft touchscreen. Objects of the class plus are showing a plus symbol that if it is touched increses a text fiel with numbers (numfield) by 1. I have different types of objects that could in theory be handed to the class plus. So I want to check whether the object that is passed is actually an object of type numfield. As somebody noted before this does not make sence in this example because nf is definded to be of type numfield. But I could easily replace numfield by a Base function of all these objects. Then - i think - it makes totally sence.

Comment: @user7408924 that's for `String` objects, not `char*` strings. For `char*` strings you're comparing pointer addresses, which in general will not work properly.

Comment: "But I could easily replace numfield by a Base function of all these objects" Why would you do that? Types are invented to use them.